# Ng-cordova localstorage not working properly in some iPhones

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm woking on a Ionic project and I'm using ng-cordova localStorage. It is working fine in android devices and It is giving some issues with some iPhones.

I've given testFlight access to the client and when he is using the application he couldn't get the data from localStorage. But I'm getting the data in my iPhone.

Are there any settings that we need to change?

Code sample

`angular.module('example', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngStorage'])
    .run(function($localStorage, $ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $localStorage.sampleData = [{
                   "id":"1",
                   "name":"userName",
                   "email":"user@sample.com"
                },{
                   "id":"2",
                   "name":"userName2",
                   "email":"user2@sample.com"
                }];
        })
    })
    .controller("sampleController",function($scope,$localStorage){
        console.log($localStorage.sampleData)
    })`

Comment: Please share how you have stored data in local storage.

Comment: Maybe for this example it would be better to use $localStorage.$default({  ... })